# I want to count values if date is today

Tags: google-sheets

I have now searched and read the last week without success.

A: A contains dates

B: B contains numbers

I would like it to count B: B if the date is today.

Hope you can help

Comment: Your intention is not clear. Do you want to COUNT how many rows in A:A have today's date? Or do you want to ADD the numbers in B:B if the date in A:A is today's date? It is always better to show the problem and solution you want, rather than to only tell about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a column C:C with the date of today in it with:
`=DATEVALUE(NOW())`

Then you can compare your date in A:A with this value:
`=IF(C1=A1;B1;0)`

Then if the date of NOW() in C1 is equal to the date in A1, it will show the value from cell B1. Else it will show zero.

Answer (score 0):

Your post is not clear.

If you want to COUNT the number of rows in A:A that have a date of TODAY:

`=ArrayFormula(COUNTIF(INT(A:A),"="&TODAY()))`

The inclusion of `INT` removes any time portions from dates if they are present. This is necessary, because TODAY() and NOW() are not equal.

If you want to SUM the number in B:B if the date in A:A is TODAY:

`=SUM(FILTER(B:B, INT(A:A)=TODAY()))`